# Since United sells fares with no carry-on allowance, should I be entitled to a fare difference refund if I am forced to gate-check my carry-on?

Tags: airlines, hand-luggage

With United Airline's Basic Economy "N" class fares, carry-on luggage that goes into the overhead bin is not allowed (mostly).  Basic Economy passengers who bring a carry-on to the gate anyway are supposed to be forced to check the bag, and fined extra for it.

So if I purchase a more costly fare that is supposed to include one carry-on, but then I am forced to gate-check my carry-on because the plane ran out of bin space, then I am essentially being downgraded to a lower class of service.

Am I entitled to a refund of the difference in fares?  Certainly if I had known that I would be denied a carry-on when I booked, then I would have purchased the cheaper fare in the first place.

United *could* (but probably doesn't) sell more N fares and less of the other economy fares to control the number of carry-on suitcases.  In other words, the airline has the ability to *not* oversell the bin space.

Comment: This feels more like a question for the Law Stack Exchange, if you are asking whether or not a company applying a limit on your service which essentially and effectively bumps you into a tier that would have cost you means you have legitimate grounds for a refund of the difference...

Comment: You aren't being downgraded to basic economy, because you're not being made to pay to gate check your bag. It's a frustrating situation, but the distinction between economy and basic economy is whether you're charged a fee for your carry on sized bag, not where that bag is transported.

Comment: @Moo I’m looking for consensus from the travel community for what constitutes a downgrade that should trigger reimbursement from an airline.  What a small claims court judge would find convincing is really just a roll of the dice.

Comment: @MJeffryes There are many other distinctions between N and the other economy classes.  The one I find relevant is the one that affects my purchasing decision: whether I am permitted to bring one carry-on suitcase with me into the cabin.  Basic Economy passengers are not.  At the time that I purchase my fare for a higher class, United says that I am.  But when I get to the gate, the attendant says I am not.

Comment: Put it another way, what if you buy a first class ticket because you want complimentary champagne... You arrive at the airport and use the priority lane to check in at the counter.  But then you are bumped to coach, and denied a refund of the fare difference because you already enjoyed some of the perks of first class by using the priority lane. Would you be good with that?  I wouldn’t.

Comment: And I would also say that the fare difference — which I have already paid — is no different from “being made to pay to gate check” in the event that I am forced to.  From the airline’s point of view, money in is money in.

Comment: Hey, you can always ask. Maybe they'll give you a useless voucher that expires before you can use it.

Comment: A general question: "since others..." is never a good legal reason. The existence of other prices, categories, "perks", etc are mostly irrelevant for your case. There are people that paid half or your fare, but so? You cannot reclaim money back. You should check just what was in your travel contract, and you agreed only with that. What do other have should be irrelevant, and it just add confusion.

Comment: @Giacomo Yes, United Airlines’ contract of carriage states, “if a Passenger is downgraded from a class of service and is not re-accommodated in a seat in an equal or greater class of service for which a fee has been paid, the Passenger is eligible for a refund of this fee.”  But obviously United would argue that I have not been downgraded because my seat has not changed, while I would argue that I have been downgraded because I am receiving service inferior to what I purchased.  U.S. law also provides that fare difference must be refunded to downgraded passengers, without defining “downgrade.”

Comment: With the ["N" fare](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/content/travel/inflight/basic-economy.aspx), you're not allowed to bring _any_ luggage except a small under-seat personal item unless you pay extra. Whereas with _your_ fare, you have a carry-on and you can also check at least one bag, right? You're still getting better service. With an "N" fare, whether your bag is a carry-on or they make you check it, you'd have to pay: "Everyone else who brings a full-sized carry-on bag to the gate will be required to check their bag and pay the applicable checked bag fee plus a $25 gate handling charge."

Comment: Now if they actually _charged_ you for checking your carry-on (and OK, it's United, so I wouldn't put it past them), then I think you have a strong case.

Comment: @Kyralessa With any other fare, I’m allowed to bring luggage _in_addition_to_ a personal item _because_ I already paid extra.  Whereas with the N fare, I would pay less up-front, but could still pay an add-on fee to check luggage on the day of travel.  With respect to bags, the only thing an N fare can’t do is carry-on a suitcase that won’t fit under the seat.  So what’s the real difference if I paid extra up-front to carry-on, and I don’t have any other bags, and then I am not allowed to carry-on?  What if the fare difference is exactly the same as the fee for N fare to check one bag?

Comment: Do we let the airline dictate what the fare difference is really for?  That would be ripe for abuse.  Imagine you are booked to fly from San Francisco to New York, but your plane has mechanical problems and you have to deplane in Oakland.  United says, you get a one dollar refund because that’s the only portion of your fare that was getting you from Oakland to New York, the other $199 we’ll keep because that was for hopping from San Francisco to Oakland.  Can you book another flight for $1 from Oakland to New York?  Could you have taken a taxi from San Francisco to Oakland for less that $199?

Comment: Bundling things together for one price is actually a marketing strategy designed to get you to pay more than you would otherwise, because it’s harder to make a rational decision when you can’t compare apples to apples.  The N fare might satisfy your needs in every way except that no carry-on would be a deal breaker, so you pay for the upgrade to get the carry-on.  Then if you are denied the carry-on, did you get all you paid for?

Comment: You got to choose you seat too, right? That's another perk you don't have if you fly basic economy.